# Removing Fields and Keys from FETCH API JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch

I'm successfully fetching data like so in React component.

```
getData = () => {
     fetch(`https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=BTC_XMR&end=9999999999&period=14400&start=1405699200`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(results => this.setState({data1:results}))
      .catch(e => e);
      }
```

the data that is returned from the API looks like this

```
   {
    date: 1405699200,
    high: 0.0047388,
    low: 0.00408001,
    open: 0.00504545,
    close: 0.00435873,
    volume: 47.34555992,
    quoteVolume: 14311.88079097,
    weightedAverage: 0.00430043
    },

 {
    date: 1405699200,
    high: 0.0045388,
    low: 0.00403001,
    open: 0.00404545,
    close: 0.00435873,
    volume: 44.34555992,
    quoteVolume: 10311.88079097,
    weightedAverage: 0.00430043
    },
```

I only need the date and close data and I need formatted without the key to be formatted like this

```
{1405699200, 0.00435873}, {1405699200, 0.00534553}
```

I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I thought about creating a function to map the data into a new variable after I mount the fetch, but this doesn't seem to be working properly.

Comment: Your data format is just values without keys..which is not valid javascript

Comment: so use an array? `[[1405699200, 0.00435873], [1405699200, 0.00534553]]` - in each el first item is volume and 2nd is average. this is supported by most charts anyway acorss the x and y axis.

Comment: Do you mean you need it to be formatted like that as a *string*? That's not a valid JS data structure. If you want an array of arrays, just do `results.map(r=>[r.date, r.close])`

Comment: yeah sorry should have said array of arrays...the map method seemingly gets the data in the right format (or so i think) but my highcharts graph isn't loading the data ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use map like this

```
getData = () => {
 fetch(`https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=BTC_XMR&end=9999999999&period=14400&start=1405699200`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(results => { 
     this.setState({
                     data1:results.map(item => {
                        return [item.date, item.close]
                     })
                  })
   })
  .catch(e => e);
  }
```